# call http:// is not working in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, http, app-transport-security

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
>   no data found: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “mobulous.co.in” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9843, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey={type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
>       0 : 
>   )}, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9f22f1c120 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9843, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9843, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates={type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
>       0 : 
>   )}}}, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “mobulous.co.in” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://mobulous.co.in/twerck/Service/snapChat, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://mobulous.co.in/twerck/Service/snapChat, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0})

Comment: This is well documented.. iOS9 enforces https unless you opt out of this manually. It's called app transfer security and you can find  more info here: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.nl/2015/08/handling-app-transport-security-in-ios-9.html

Answer (score 2):

Update:

As of Xcode 7.1, you don't need to manually enter the NSAppTransportSecurity Dictionary in the info.plist.

It will now autocomplete for you, realize it's a dictionary, and then autocomplete the Allows Arbitrary Loads as well. info.plist

- [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOomz.png)